# Hyperledger Fabric: What is the use of clientauth flag in peer channel create?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

My understanding of clientauth is that this is something that is enabled on a server so that it will only let a client connect after client has presented a valid TLS certificate. Is that correct?

If so, then why is clientauth a flag that can be set as one of the arguments to the [peer channel create](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/commands/peerchannel.html) command?

```
--clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
```

when a channel is being created, isn't the orderer the server? and the machine on which `peer channel create` is executed is the client? so then why are we turning on `clientauth` on the client? what does that accomplish if anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding of clientauth is that this is something that is
>   enabled on a server so that it will only let a client connect after
>   client has presented a valid TLS certificate. Is that correct?

Yes.

> If so, then why is clientauth a flag that can be set as one of the
>   arguments to the peer channel create command?

*Because without it the client does not present its TLS certificate to the server.* So if the client is trying to communicate with a server on which clientauth is enabled and the `peer channel create` is executed without this flag, there is an error message in the logs. Something like:

```
2019-03-12 23:33:59.975 UTC [core/comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 022 TLS handshake failed with error tls: client didn't provide a certificate {"server": "PeerServer", "remote address": ""}
```

> when a channel is being created, isn't the orderer the server?

Yes

> and the machine on which peer channel create is executed is the client?

Yes

> so then why are we turning on clientauth on the client? what does that accomplish if anything?

answered earlier

Answer (score 2):

the flag description (above) captures it perfectly.

TLS communication can use both one-way (server only) and two-way (server and client) authentication. A peer node is both a TLS server and a TLS client. It is the former when another peer node, application, or the CLI makes a connection to it, and the latter when it makes a connection to another peer node or orderer.

The flag is to enable that client auth is required on the peer - by default it is off (when TLS is enabled on a peer node). Its a means of identifying the client to the server (a Peer and an Orderer may both have client auth enabled in a mutual TLS setup for example).